# State not updating in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am trying to update the state when I run it, no error is shown and the `console.log` output is showing that the state has not updated. Can anyone help in figuring out what is wrong?

Here is the function that is supposed to update the state.

```
  addDay(newDay) {
    console.log(this.state.allSkiDays);
    this.setState({
      allSkiDays: [...this.state.allSkiDays, newDay]
    });
    console.log(this.state.allSkiDays);
  },
```

where I declared the initial state

```
export const App = createReactClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      allSkiDays: [
        {
          resort: "Skaq Valley",
          date: "1 / 2 / 2020",
          powder: true,
          backcountry: false
        }
      ]
    };

    this.addDay = this.addDay.bind(this);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is async and when you log your state after set it , react runs your log before set state . You can run set state sync as below :

```
 addDay(newDay) {
     console.log(this.state.allSkiDays);
     this.setState({
          allSkiDays: [...this.state.allSkiDays, newDay]
      }, ()=>{
          console.log(this.state.allSkiDays)
      });
 }
```

Now you can see updated state in the console because your seState runs sync.

Comment: this seems to have worked but the updated state is not being used when I try to load from the state ```           <SkiDayList days={this.state.allSkiDays} filter={} /> ``` still only loads the initial state.

Comment: Use es5 syntax for initial state like this: `getInitialState: function() {return yourState}`. You've used es6 syntax for initial state but create ReactClass is es5 syntax.